# Why does .currentFrame not find frames within movie clip? my button is not hiding. Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, hide

I'm creating a "simple" slideshow for my sister using Flash CS5 AS3. I'm using the flash presentation template. I currently have the existing functional buttons that navigate any direction through the presentation. The only thing is that on the cover page, I just want to have an "Enter" button that hides when you move to frames > 1. I currently have the buttons all on one layer, the movieclip (slides_mc) on a separate layer, and the actions on it's own layer. All consisting of just one frame across on the main timeline. Within slides_mc there is no actionscript, and consists of 4 frames.

I'm getting no errors whatsoever when I run a test, but it's simply not finding specific frames within the movie clip. OR it's finding the frames but not executing .visible=false.

If I use the following:

```
if(slides_mc.currentFrame>1) enter_btn.visible=false;
```

It the button is visible on all four frames.

If I use the following:

```
if(slides_mc.currentFrame==1) enter_btn.visible=false;
```

The button disappears on frame 1, but never becomes visible again on any of the other frames.

If use the following:

```
if(slides_mc.currentFrame==2) enter_btn.visible=false;
```

The button is visible on all four frames.

Do I need to put this code within a function to call this and make it work?? Thanks in advance. This button hide issue is driving me nuts. I really need to go back to multimedia school.

If I forgot to mention crucial info or if you need to see any of the other code that may be affecting the outcome please let me know. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, all code is on the actionscript layer on frame one of the main timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doThis);

 function doThis(){ if(slides_mc.currentFrame>1){enter_btn.visible=false;}}
```

Then the function would be checking for the currentFrame all the time.

Comment: Thanks Sean! You were on the right track. I just needed to tweak a couple things and it's doing exactly what I want now from the main actionscript frame rather than throwing actionscript into the movie clip. I tried the "event.ENTER_FRAME" call at one point before, but I don't think I formatted the function right. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: A huge thanks to Sean for giving me some direction. Here is the fully functioning answer to my question above. As Sean had pointed out, it was the stage.addEventListener and a function that was needed in order to communicate with the slides_mc throughout the timeline.

Here it is:

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hidebtn);

function hidebtn(event:Event):void 
{ 
if(slides_mc.currentFrame>=2)
{
    enter_btn.visible=false;
}
else {enter_btn.visible=true}
    }
works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You probably put code in 1st frame , "if" is checked once and when You move to next frame this code is not executed . If You dont like to extend MovieClip for external .as file , You should simply put code visible = false on frames You need to hide it , or simply remove object from timeline .

Comment: It is current working as I wanted thanks to you. I added actionscript within the movieclip in order to hide the button, I'm kinda confused as to why the actionscript gets checked only once even if its on the main timeline and the movieclip is navigating within it. I have other code within the actionscript on the main timeline (frame1) that works perfectly. It must be that they are functions called by addEventListener?? So confused. Glad you helped me out! Thanks.

Comment: yeah, they are called manually by events or event that is automatically generated code by the Flash IDE... try throw new Error("bla") on some frame and you should see the name of the function (it would be something like frame1() or frame2()...

Comment: @ Travis : its because this what You writing in frame , after compile to swf is function and MovieClip call this function when move to this frame . On start You move to 1st frame and swf call You function , but when You move to next frames , there was no more functions to call :] You may also try Sean idea, but i think You should addEventListener to Your MovieClip .

Answer (score -2):

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doThis);

 function doThis(event:Event){ if(slides_mc.currentFrame>1){enter_btn.visible=false;}}
```

Comment: This answer needs some explanation.